# Rellenar input text en funcion del valor de otro input text

Tags: php, html

Tengo una tabla producto la cual tiene código, nombre, etc..
entonces al momento de ingresar el código del producto en formulario, automáticamente coloque el nombre de ese producto...

```
<form  accept-charset="utf-8">  
    <div class="form-group" id='mcodigo'>
        <label>Código</label> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Código" id='codigo' name='codigo' autofocus>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id='nombre' name='nombre'>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues hay una funcion que se llama change() en jquery, en el que capturas el valor de la siguiente manera.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // Se ejecuta una vez que el DOM de la pagina este listo
        $( "#codigo" ).change(function() { //Captura cada vez que vea un cambio en el input con id "codigo"
              //Ejecuta la accion a realizar
        });
});
```

Aquí la pregunta es: ¿Tienes un controlador, que al pasar un parametro (el codigo), te devuelve los parametros que necesitas de vuelta? y ¿Tienes una conexion con la base de datos, y la query que necesita para ello?

Estas preguntas son clave, por que la idea es que cada vez que cambie de dato en este input, se ejecute un ajax el cual hará una llamada asíncrona a buscar tus datos en tiempo real, a el controlador, donde se le pasara el parámetro "código" y este al ejecutar una consulta a la base de datos, devolverá la información que se necesite, y a través del mismo ajax, dejaremos la o las respuestas en sus respectivos inputs. Saludos!

Comment: Me gusta la idea,,.yo he estado investigando al parecer con cuerda con tu explicación pero me gustaría que ayudaras un poco mas de como podria yo hacerlo a traves de una funcion y llamarla por el metodo ajax..,

Comment: Tienes la query de tu bbdd?

Comment: con que lenguaje estas trabajando en el servidor? Java, Php, asp, para que te pueda guiar al menos

Comment: lenguaje php, y motor de base de datos mysql

Comment: tienes hecha la conexion entre tu base de datos y el controlador?

Comment: cuanto a conexiones con la bd si ya estan echas.,,

Comment: perfecto, crea otro archivo php, y llama a la clase conexion, para separar la conexion de lo que sera el controlador y puedas trabajar mas estructuralmente. Para incluir en un php en otro, debes llamar a la funcion include('conexion.php'); donde claramente conexion,php es el archivo donde dejas la conexion hecha con la bbdd

Comment: Estos pasos que dices ya los tengo hecho,.,

Comment: Perfecto!!!! estas ocupando mysql_connect o mysqli_connect? y que version de php estas trabajando?

Comment: php 5 y mysql_connect

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

include('Conexion.php');

$codigo = $_POST["codigo"];

if (!$con) {
    echo 'No pudo conectarse a mysql';
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('BASE DE DATOS', $con)) {
    echo 'No pudo seleccionar la base de datos';
    exit;
}

$sql       = 'SELECT nombre FROM TABLADEDATOS WHERE codigo = '.$codigo; //solo un ejemplo de la consulta
$resultado = mysql_query($sql, $con);

if (!$resultado) {
    echo "Error de BD, no se pudo consultar la base de datos\n";
    echo "Error MySQL: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}


$pila = array();
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
      array_push($pila, $fila['nombre']);
}

echo json_encode($pila);

mysql_free_result($resultado);


?>
```

Considera $con como la variable de conexión para conectarse a la clase de esta misma.
Se pasa el include de la conexion, luego capturas por el "POST" el codigo que le has de pasar desde la pagina web a el controlador. Luego haces unas consultas para ver si te puedes conectar con la bbdd y con la tabla que necesitas.
Posterior a eso haces una consulta, lo montas en una variable y haces la consulta a la bbdd con mysql_query donde hará la llamada a la BBDD. Si este tiene problemas, te regresara un error, y si no colocara el resultado en un array como nuevo elemento. Una vez recorrido todos los resultados, te devolverá un json, donde en jquery por medio de ajax lo capturaras.

Avísame cuando tengas estos pasos listos, y perdón por la demora.

Comment: okey.,,.gracias lo revisare.,,

Comment: @ChekeSanchez te aconsejo a utilizar `MySQLi*`, ya que la extensión `MySQL*` fue declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0` y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0.` En su lugar debería utilizarse las extensiones `MySQLi` o `PDO_MySQL`. http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: gracias por tus recomendaciones., Lo tomare en cuenta.,

Comment: Como bien dijo es de PHP 5.5, pero estas trabajando con PHP 5.0 xDD por eso coloque esa conexión

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda yo tengo un problema al querer seleccionar los datos de mi base de datos, espero me puedas ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91211/mostrar-resultado-en-inputs-con-b%c3%basqueda-sql?noredirect=1#comment168129_91211