# Completar el resto del formulario según el valor de un input

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

Anteriormente seguí un ejemplo para poner en practica el rellenado de inputs a partir de un input padre y a funcionado correctamente, pero al momento de implementarlo en mi aplicación fracaso en mi intento y no me trae nada de la base de datos, y en consola no me marca ningun error.  El input nombre es con el que se debe de identificar. Estoy usando *PHP 7* y el *Admin LTE*.

```css
$(function() {
  /* Ponemos evento blur a la escucha sobre id nombre en id cliente. */
  $('#cliente').on('blur', '#nombre', function() {
    /* Obtenemos el valor del campo */
    var valor=this.value;
    /* Si la longitud del valor es mayor a 2 caracteres.. */
    if(valor.length>=3) {
      /* Cambiamos el estado.. */
      $('#estado').html('Cargando datos de servidor...');
      /* Hacemos la consulta ajax */
      var consulta=$.ajax( {
        type:'POST', url:'cliente.php', data: {
          nombre: valor
        }
        , dataType:'JSON'
      }
      );
      /* En caso de que se haya retornado bien.. */
      consulta.done(function(data) {
        if(data.error!==undefined) {
          $('#estado').html('Ha ocurrido un error: '+data.error);
          return false;
        }
        else {
          if(data.destino!==undefined) {
            $('#nombre #destino').val(data.destino);
          }
          if(data.viatico!==undefined) {
            $('#nombre #viatico').val(data.viatico);
          }
          if(data.casetas!==undefined) {
            $('#nombre #casetas').val(data.casetas);
          }
          if(data.extras!==undefined) {
            $('#nombre #extras').val(data.extras);
          }
          if(data.diesel!==undefined) {
            $('#nombre #diesel').val(data.diesel);
          }
          if(data.desgaste!==undefined) {
            $('#nombre #desgaste').val(data.desgaste);
          }
          if(data.utilidad!==undefined) {
            $('#nombre #utilidad').val(data.utilidad);
          }
          if(data.total!==undefined) {
            $('#nombre #total').val(data.total);
          }
          $('#estado').html('Datos cargados..');
          return true;
        }
      }
      );
      /* Si la consulta ha fallado.. */
      consulta.fail(function() {
        $('#estado').html('Ha habido un error contactando el servidor.');
        return false;
      }
      );
    }
    else {
      /* Mostrar error */
      $('#estado').html('El nombre tener una longitud mayor a 2 caracteres...');
      return false;
    }
  }
  );
}

);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="formulario" id="formulario" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="hidden" name="idventa" id="idventa">
    <label>Numero de viaje:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="num_viaje" id="num_viaje" maxlength="256" placeholder="Número de viaje" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Cliente:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="256" placeholder="Cliente">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Destino:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="destino" id="destino" maxlength="256" placeholder="Destino">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Operador:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="operador" id="operador" maxlength="256" placeholder="Operador" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Número de operador:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idoperador" id="idoperador" maxlength="256" placeholder="Numero de operador" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Tipo de operación:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tipoOperacion" id="tipoOperacion" maxlength="256" placeholder="Tipo de operación" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Viatico:</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="viatico" id="viatico" maxlength="256" placeholder="Viatico" required onchange="sumar(this.value);">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Caseta:</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="casetas" id="casetas" maxlength="256" placeholder="Casetas" required onchange="sumar(this.value);">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Extras:</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="extras" id="extras" maxlength="256" placeholder="Extras" required onchange="sumar(this.value);">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Cantidad en Diesel:</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="diesel" id="diesel" maxlength="256" placeholder="Diesel" required onchange="sumar(this.value);">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Desgaste 5%:</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="desgaste" id="desgaste" maxlength="256" placeholder="Desgaste 5%" onchange="sumar(this.value);">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Utilidad:</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="utilidad" id="utilidad" maxlength="256" placeholder="Utilidad" onchange="sumar(this.value);">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Inversión total:</label>
    <span id="spTotal"></span>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="total" id="total" maxlength="256" placeholder="Total">
  </div>
  <div id="estado">Esperando input.</div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnGuardar"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>

    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cancelarform()" type="button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Cancelar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
<?php

/* Conectar a una base de datos de MySQL invocando al controlador */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbsistema;host=localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$contraseña = '';

try {
    $gbd = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contraseña);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Falló la conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if(!empty($_POST['nombre'])){ 

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre = '$nombre'";  
$stmt = $gbd->prepare($sql);
$stmt ->execute();
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($arrDatos);
  if($arrDatos){
    foreach ($arrDatos as $row) {
      if ($nombre = $row['nombre']) {
        $return = array (
            'destino'=>$row['destino'],
            'viatico'=>$row['viatico'],
            'casetas'=>$row['casetas'],
            'extras'=>$row['extras'],
            'diesel'=>$row['diesel'], 
            'desgaste'=>$row['desgaste'],
            'utilidad'=>$row['utilidad'],
            'total'=>$row['total']
        );
      }      
    }
  } else {
    $return = array('error'=>'El nombre no esta guardado en la base de datos');
  }
  die(json_encode($return));
}
```

Comment: Podes ir a la página en donde tenes el problema y mediante el atajo `Ctrl+Shift+Q` acceder a la pestaña *Red* de las *herramientas para desarrolladores*. Una vez hecho eso, trata de enviar el formulario. ¿Te aparece una petición `XHR` que solicita los datos a tu `archivo.php`? Si haces click sobre la petición podes ver los datos de la solicitud en *cabecera* y la respuesta en la pestaña del mismo nombre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a intentar corregir un poco el código:

```
if(!empty($_POST['nombre']))
{ 

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre = :nombre";  
    $stmt = $gbd->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":nombre",$nombre);
    $stmt ->execute();
    $arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //Verifica si no hay datos en la consulta
    if(!$arrDatos)
    {
        $arrDatos = array('error'=>'El nombre no esta guardado en la base de datos');
    }

} else {
        //Esto ocurre si el nombre está vacío solamente
        $arrDatos = array('error'=>'El nombre está vacío');
}

//Imprimir los resultados 
header('Content-Type: application/json'); //A no ser que ya esté seteado en otra parte
echo(json_encode($arrDatos));
```

En mi otra respuesta expliqué con más claridad lo de las consultas preparadas.

La forma correcta es:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre = :nombre";
```

y luego:

```
    $stmt->bindValue(":nombre",$nombre);
```

Luego, este método:

```
    $arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

te crea un arreglo con los resultados. No tienes tú que crear el arreglo. Esa es una de las maravillas de PDO, entre otras. Luego, lo imprimes en formato JSON:

```
    echo(json_encode($arrDatos));
```

Si la petición espera algo en formato JSON, no puedes imprimir nada más que eso, así que puede que el var_dump que tenías te estuviera dando problema. Incluso a veces hay que poner esto antes del echo:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

O sea, al final de todo:

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo(json_encode($arrDatos));
```

**Eso es lo único que debe salir por pantalla en tu script, nada más.**

Comment: he cambiado mi codigo por tu respuesta, pero apesar de ello, sigue sin mostrarme los demas inputs con sus valores

Comment: Lo primero que debes verificar es si estás obteniendo datos cuando haces la petición.  En jQuery, puedes poner después de: `consulta.done(function(data) { `  lo siguiente: `console.log(data);` y debes verificar lo que se imprime en la consola, activando el visor de consola Javascript de tu navegador. Si no se imprime nada significa que algo anda mal en la consulta, del lado del archivo PHP.

Comment: no me muestra nada en consola, estoy usando firefox, crees que el problema sea que el footer lo tengo por aparte? por que si uso la respuesta en mi otro ejemplo con el que practique si funciona

Comment: Fíijate que tu `onblur` está basado en algo que tiene el id `Cliente` pero no veo nada en el HTML que tenga ese id. Puede que ni siquiera esté entrando en tu código jQuery. Verifica que entra en cada parte del código poniendo por ejemplo `alert("ok");`

Comment: acabo de ver ese error de id cliente, se lo he agregado, el form lo metro de un div con dicho id, en la consola ya me muestra un resultado de        `Array [ Object, Object ]` pero no me coloca en arreglo en los inputs, es por ello que anteriormente hacia el arreglo manualmente